# "Who/whom was this street named after?"

Tags: case

I would like to know whom a street was named after. That's how I am asking it:

> **Whom** was this street named after?

Is the question correct?

Comment: It's correct, but it sounds rather stuffy. Most people would use 'who'.

Comment: It's not very conversational. 'Who' sounds much more natural.

Comment: Although whom is certainly on the wane in informal situations, there are enough grammar websites devoting screenfuls of advice about how to use who and whom correctly to prove that many English-speakers still care about such things.                  In everyday conversation, when we’re speaking to friends, family, or colleagues, whom rarely gets a look-in: people use who all the time and may view whom as rather stuffy or pretentious.

Comment: Well I'm stuffy and proud, so I would say 'After whom is this street named?'.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is. But many people nowadays don't use *whom* at all, and would say (and write):

> Who was this street named after?

Anyone who claims that this is not grammatical is living in an earlier century.

Answer (score -1):

> **Whom** was this street named after?

Yes, it is correct.

However, if you were to use *who* in that sentence, it would be wrong because the **subject** is *this street* since it is doing the action. We use *whom* as an **object** receiving an action.

In this case,

**object** → (unknown person)

**subject** → this street

**verb** → named after

So, *whom* would be correct.

> **Who** was being named after this street?

In this case,

**subject** → (unknown person)

**verb** → being named after

**noun** → this street

---

**Add-on:** *This street* cannot be a subject in this case because this is a question of missing person although it would fit.

**i.e.**

**subject** → this street

**verb** → was being named after

**noun** → Obama

---

Thus, **who** would be the correct answer for this sentence.

Comment: I don't know who the "we" are who "use _whom_ as an **object** receiving an action", but it doesn't include many English speakers in the 21st Century.

Comment: @ColinFine, but still tested during English exam since it's still in syllable.

Comment: Well, then the people who created the syllabus are interested in something other than teaching people to speak English.

Comment: @ColinFine, it'd be under Grammar section. They're testing English knowledge. Speaking is Oral.

Comment: Yes, speaking is oral. (That's what "oral" means). And the grammar of spoken English, for most people today, does not include the word "whom". (Yes, I'm teasing. I know perfectly well that many people use the word "grammar" to mean "an arbitrary set of rules, based on what some people think the language _ought_ to be, and used to distinguish the superior people who follow it from the inferior who don't". I prefer to use "grammar" in the linguist's sense of "The rules that people actually follow in using their language".).